# How to prevent horizontal scrolling on a web app?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

When I reduce the width of my browser to the smallest possible amount, I still see the user has the ability to scroll horizontally.  Given that I'm using Twitter Bootstrap, I expected this not to be the case.  How do I prevent this from happening on this page:

http://warm-chamber-7399.herokuapp.com/

Comment: `.navbar-inner` has negative margins on all sides which cause it to be wider than `<body>`, which in turn causes the horizontal scrollbar. Either adjust that, or do overflow:hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need-

```
.navbar-wrapper {
    max-width:100%;
    //your other CSS
}
```

Don't apply it to body or other elements as it can screw things up.

Comment: This seems to prevent the horizontal scroll, but now the top nav bar seems to be cut off when I decrease the width of the browser to it's lowest point.  Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried max-width instead of overflow. Like in my re-edited code above.

Comment: @sharataka define `max-width` and `min-width`.

Comment: As i've written in my code above in your CSS .nav-wrapper. This will mean the wrapper will not exceed 100% of the screen width (overflow and cause a scroll bar)

Comment: ok I just looked at your site, I was fed up of guessing ;). The problem is   .navbar-inner {margin: -20px;}   CSS. Remove this and it will fix it. I just ran it using chrome dev and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! But the problem I have now is that there is white space on top of the navbar?  Any idea on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
body{ overflow-x: hidden;}
```